# Control on Calendar Primefaces component

Tags: primefaces, controls

I am using `p:calendar` Primefaces component for specifying 2 dates : start and end.

An evident control is to verify if end date is not before start date. 
Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

```
<p:outputLabel for="startDate" value="#{msg.StartDate}" />
    <p:calendar id="startDate" value="#{employeeBean.employee.startDate}" required="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" language="#{msg.CalendarLanguage}" mask="true"
                                requiredMessage="#{msg.required}">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="endDate" />
    </p:calendar>
    <p:message for="startDate" />

<p:outputLabel for="endDate" value="#{msg.EndDate}" />
    <p:calendar id="endDate" mindate="#{employeeBean.employee.startDate}" value="#{employeeBean.employee.endDate}" required="false" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"
                                language="#{msg.CalendarLanguage}" mask="true">
    </p:calendar>
<p:message for="endDate" />
```